# Crear expresiones regulares para poder identificar horarios

Tags: php, laravel

```
$timings = "11 AM to 11 PM (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Sun), 11 AM to 11:30 PM (Fri), 11 AM to 1 PM (Sat)";

$dayTime = explode('),', $timings);//11 AM to 11 PM (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Sun),
$longitud = count($dayTime);

//Recorro todos los elementos
for($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++)
      {
       echo $dayTime[$i];
       echo "<br>";
      }
```

** quiero separar las horas y los dias para insertar un registro con hora por cada dia
por ejemplo:
primer valor de la cadena:
11 AM to 11 PM (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Sun) 
y que se haga algo así 
(11:00:00,23:00:00,1)
(11:00:00,23:00:00,2)
(11:00:00,23:00:00,3)
(11:00:00,23:00:00,4)
(11:00:00,23:00:00,5)
**

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta ahora? ¿Necesariamente debe ser con expresiones regulares?

Comment: no necesariamente, estaba pensando en algo tipo un switch pero seria una cantidad muy grande de posibilidades

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? Se puede hacer con `explode()`, solo revisa cada línea para encontrar patrones.

Comment: el problema es que son muy ireguares los horarias en algunos solo es 11am sun.mon entre paréntesis y en otros no

Comment: ¿Cómo sería la sentencia para insertar un horario con su respectivo día?

Comment: seria insertar un horario por cada dia respecto a el horario correspondiente con su numero de dia  sun[0] - mon[1]

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar un ejemplo de cómo insertarías uno de esos datos.

Comment: aun no tengo una idea en concreto pero ahí esta un ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$timings = "11 AM to 10 PM (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Sun), 11 AM to 10:59 PM (Fri)";
$timings = "24 Hours (Mon-Sun)";
$timings = "11 AM to 10:30 PM (Mon-Thu),11:30 AM to 11:30 PM (Fri),12 Noon to 11:30 PM (Sat),12 Noon to 10:30 PM (Sun)";
$daysOrder = array("Sun" => "0","Mon" => "1","Tue" => "2","Wed" => "3","Thu" => "4","Fri" => "5","Sat" => "6","Sun" => "7");
$schedule = array();
$timings = str_replace("Noon","AM",$timings);
$dayTime = explode('),', $timings);//11 AM to 11 PM (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Sun),
//print_r($dayTime);
$longitud = count($dayTime);
//print($longitud);
//Recorro todos los elementos
if(strpos(implode(" ",$dayTime), '24 Hours') !== false){
    horariesLineal($dayTime,$longitud,$daysOrder,$schedule); 
}else{
    horariesMultiDay ($dayTime,$longitud,$daysOrder,$schedule);
}

function horariesMultiDay ($dayTime,$longitud,$daysOrder,$schedule) {
$dayTime1 = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++)
    {    
        array_push($dayTime1,$dayTime[$i]);
        $hours = explode(' (', $dayTime1[$i]);
        $hours[1] = str_replace(")","",$hours[1]);
        if (strpos(implode(" ",$hours), '-') !== false) {
            $days = explode("-", $hours[1]);

            $star = $daysOrder[trim($days[0])];
            $limit = $daysOrder[trim($days[1])];

            for ($o = $star; $o < $limit; $o++)
            {
                echo $o.'='.$star.' '.$o.' < '.$limit.' '.$o.'++ <br>';
                $horarios = explode('to', $hours[0]);
                $hour1 = date( "H:i:s", strtotime($horarios[0])); 
                $hour2 = date( "H:i:s", strtotime($horarios[1]));
                $schedule[] = [
                    'weekday' => str_replace("7","0",$o),
                    'open_time' => $hour1,
                    'close_time' => $hour2
                ];

            }
        }else{
            $days = explode(",", $hours[1]);
            for ($o = 0; $o < count($days); $o++)
            {
                $horarios = explode('to', $hours[0]);
                $hour1 = date( "H:i:s", strtotime($horarios[0])); 
                $hour2 = date( "H:i:s", strtotime($horarios[1]));
                $schedule[] = [
                    'weekday' => str_replace("7","0",$daysOrder[trim($days[$o])]),
                    'open_time' => $hour1,
                    'close_time' => $hour2
                ];

            }
        }
    }
    print_r($schedule);
}

function horariesLineal ($dayTime,$longitud,$daysOrder,$schedule){
    $dayTime1 = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++)
    {    
        array_push($dayTime1,$dayTime[$i]);
        $hours = explode(' (', $dayTime1[$i]);
        $hours[1] = str_replace(")","",$hours[1]);
        if (strpos(implode(" ",$hours), '-') !== false) {
            $days = explode("-", $hours[1]);
            $limit = $daysOrder[trim($days[1])];
            for ($o = 0; $o < $limit; $o++)
            {
                $schedule[] = [
                    'weekday' => $o,
                    'open_time' => '00:00:00',
                    'close_time' => '00:00:00'
                ];

            }
    }
}
    print_r($schedule);
}
```

*** solo me falta como hacer para identificar cuando es un rango de dias por ejemplo aqui 11 AM to 10:30 PM (Mon-Thu) ***